# Compiling Qt 5.3 for arm with OpenGL ES 2.0 support gives "cannot find -lGLESv2"

Tags: qt, opengl-es, arm, cross-compiling

I am compiling Qt 5.3 for ARM with following `qmake.conf` :

```
MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
CONFIG                 += incremental
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../../common/linux.conf)
include(../../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../../common/g++-unix.conf)

load(device_config)

QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM = eglfs

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = $${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
QMAKE_LINK              = $${QMAKE_CXX}
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = $${QMAKE_CXX}

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = $${CROSS_COMPILE}ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = $${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy
QMAKE_NM                = $${CROSS_COMPILE}nm -P
QMAKE_STRIP             = $${CROSS_COMPILE}strip

COMPILER_FLAGS          = -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp

#modifications to gcc-base.conf
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += $${COMPILER_FLAGS}
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS         += $${COMPILER_FLAGS}
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3

QMAKE_LIBS             += -lrt -lpthread -ldl

# Extra stuff (OpenGL, DirectFB, ...)
QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL        = $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/
QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL        = $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL     = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL     = $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENVG     = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENVG     = $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL}

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL          = -lEGL -lIMGegl -lsrv_um
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL       = -lGLESv2 $${QMAKE_LIBS_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2   = -lGLESv2 $${QMAKE_LIBS_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENVG       = -lOpenVG $${QMAKE_LIBS_EGL}

# Sanity check
deviceSanityCheckCompiler()

load(qt_config)
```

I have OpenGL ES dev packages installed

```
ii  libgles2-mesa:amd64                                   10.3.0~git20140618.88b887fa-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  libgles2-mesa-dbg:amd64                               10.3.0~git20140618.88b887fa-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- debugging symbols
ii  libgles2-mesa-dev                                     10.3.0~git20140618.88b887fa-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty     amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- development files
```

After running my configure :

```
configure -opengl es2 -skip qtwebkit -skip qtdeclarative -no-sse4.2 -no-sse4.1 -no-sse3 -no-sse2 -no-cups -no-openssl -no-kms -no-nis -no-pch -no-mips_dspr2 -no-mips_dsp -no-accessibility -opensource -confirm-license -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- -no-xcb -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -prefix ~/programming/tools/qt/qt-arm-5.3  -platform linux-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -device linux-arm-cortex9-mine-g++ -v
```

I get the following in the end :

```
OpenGL ES 2.x auto-detection... ()
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp -O2 -O3 -Wall -W -fPIE  -I/home/USER/programming/tools/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-arm-cortex9-mine-g++ -I/home/USER/programming/tools/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0/qtbase/config.tests/unix/opengles2 -I/usr/include:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/ -I. -o opengles2.o /home/USER/programming/tools/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0/qtbase/config.tests/unix/opengles2/opengles2.cpp
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-O1 -o opengles2 opengles2.o   -lrt -lpthread -ldl -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lIMGegl -lsrv_um 
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lIMGegl
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lsrv_um
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opengles2] Error 1
OpenGL ES 2.x disabled.
The OpenGL ES 2.0 functionality test failed!
 You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
 QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2, QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2 in
 /home/USER/programming/tools/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-arm-cortex9-mine-g++.
```

My libs are located in here (I think that is what it is looking for) :

```
$ ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 cze 18 08:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so -> mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so
```

Comment: That's your ***host*** `libGLESv2`. You need a cross-compiled one in your sysroot. Where is it?

Comment: @peppe I just got the same conclusion but the problem is: I just wanted to compile it to test if I can do it when I get my ARM cortex-a9 board. Where can I get the ARM binaries for OpenGL ES 2.0 or how can I build that? The only thing that I was able to find were OpenGL ES headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to link `x86` libraries for my ARM build and in my own ignorance I didn't know that OpenGL is just a standard therefore there are only headers available.

So the solution for my problem would be to compile some OpenGL ES implementation e.g. [mesa3d](http://mesa3d.org) for ARM and then link those binaries to Qt.

Comment: Have you done this? Can you provide a tutorial? I am stuck at this point